# Problem with the command "npm install fs"

Tags: javascript, json

I am not used to work with Linux, so maybe this is a silly question. In the lab that I am working on, I am asked to run the command "npm install fs" to read/write files.

But here is the error that i have and I don't know how to solve it, i couldn't find similar problems too.

PS: I am working on Ubuntu 17.10.

[image]

Comment: I believe fs doesnot need to be installed. You can just require it and use it easily. Just in case you can create a package.json file inside the lab1.

Comment: Why are you trying to install something that's [part of the standard Node.js library](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)? Having said that, I can entirely recommend installing `fs-extra` and using that instead of `fs`, since it just wraps the standard `fs` but adds a few functions that are _indispensible_ if you're doing proper filesystem stuff.

Comment: you actually installed this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fs` is a module that doesn't have to be installed. It comes part of node.js core so you only need to *require* it in your code.

Instead of running `npm install fs --save`, just add the following line in the file you're wanting to use it in:

`const fs = require('fs');`

Here are the docs: https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-fs-module

However, to address your question, the error message your receiving is likely due to the fact that:

1. You don't have a package.json in your project
2. You are not in the correct directory when running `npm install ...` and therefore it cannot find your package.json.

I believe your mistake is that you skipped the part where you initialize your npm repository (which generates your package.json).

To initialize an npm repo, do the following:

1. Navigate to your project root directory
2. Run `npm init` and follow the instructions if when prompted.